# Reload MDI Parent from child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to reload Mdi Parent form in one of my child form event.

I have used below code but it is not working

```
//Child form even
private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.ParentForm.Refresh();
}
```

what is the solution please any one suggest me.

Comment: _but it is not working_ - do you get an exception?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici no exception is there , but it is not Reloading.

Comment: Have you tried using the `MdiParent` property instead of `ParentForm`?

Comment: @JohnWillemse How can I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean of "reload"? If you want to reset the state of all the controls, you have to do it manually. If you want to raise the `Load` event, you can't. Describe your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1) You must make sure that the MDI parent form has the property `IsMdiContainer` set to `true`.
2) You must make sure that the child form's `MdiParent` property is set to the parent form:

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
child.MdiParent = this;
child.Show();
```

3) Then you can access the MDI parent from a child with the `MdiParent` property:

```
this.MdiParent.Refresh(); // or this.MdiParent.Invalidate();
```

Comment: still its not working,  I need to call Load event of MdiParent form

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to execute the body of the `Load` event of the parent form, you should redesign your classes in a way that allows the code to be invoked multiple times.

For example suppose you have a form named `Form1`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeFormData();
    }

    public void InitializeFormData()
    {
        // do the initialization
    }
}
```

Now you can easily call the `InitializeFormData` method on any child form:

```
((Form1)this.MdiParent).InitializeFormData();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code in parent form to re-draw UI,

```
this.Controls.Clear();

this.InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: I facing similar problem once, I redraw UI and it's work for me

Comment: Before suggesting something, you better understand the consequences. What you have suggested may work in some situations, but it doesn't work (and ruin the form) most of the times. And by all means, it is not the correct solution to any problem.

Comment: I don't think, it's ruined anything here. don't be jurk, be nice and make stackoverflow better place to help each other. Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I annoyed you. I didn't meant to do that. I just wanted to "make stackoverflow a better place". There is always a better way than what you have said. That's my opinion.